# Encontrar y devolver listas que estan en una matriz

Tags: python, python-3.x, estructuras-de-datos

necesito ayuda con esto, dada dos matrices:

```
a = [[bogota, cundinamarca,13013,0,0,0,0], [cartagena,bolivar,12002,1,1,1,1], [leticia,amazonas,140012,0,0,0,0]]

b = [[bogota,cundinamarca,13013], [cartagena,bolivar,12002]]
```

como hago para crear una nueva matriz "c" que dada la matriz b, busque en la matriz principal "a"
las que tengan los mismos elementos en los indices  0, 1 y 2, y las agregue a "c", es decir que c sea asi:

```
c = [[bogota, cundinamarca,13013,0,0,0,0], [cartagena,bolivar,12002,1,1,1,1]]
```

pd. La matriz principal "a" es mucho mas grande que la matriz "b"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con in ciclo `for` o de forma mas optima con una comprensión de lista, donde recorreremos la lista `a` y comprobaremos si su elemento esta en la lista `b`

```py
a = [["bogota", "cundinamarca",13013,0,0,0,0], ["cartagena","bolivar",12002,1,1,1,1], ["leticia","amazonas",140012,0,0,0,0]]
b = [["bogota","cundinamarca",13013], ["cartagena","bolivar",12002]]

c = [y for y in a if y[:3] in b]
```

Utilizamos la notación de slice para solo verificar los 3 primeros elementos, puesto que la lista `b` contiene `[bogota,cundinamarca,13013]` y la lista `a` contienen muchos mas `[bogota, cundinamarca,13013,0,0,0,0]`

**resultado**

```
[['bogota', 'cundinamarca', 13013, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['cartagena', 'bolivar', 12002, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

**con ciclo `for` tradicional**

```py
c = []
for y in a:
    if y[:3] in b:
        c.append(y[:3])
        
print(c)
```

Por lo que veo en los comentarios, quieres que mantenga el orden, en ese caso puedes utilizar la siguiente comprensión de lista.

```py
a = [["bogota", "cundinamarca",13013,0,0,0,0], ["cartagena","bolivar",12002,1,1,1,1], ["leticia","amazonas",140012,0,0,0,0]]
#cambie el orden para que veas que se mantiene
b = [["cartagena","bolivar",12002],["bogota","cundinamarca",13013]]

#almacenamos x que es el dato de la lista a
c = [x for y in b for x in a if y == x[:3]]
```

Es necesario recorre la lista `a` por que solo hay coincidencia hasta ciertos elementos (los primmeros 3)

**resultado**

```
[['cartagena', 'bolivar', 12002, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 ['bogota', 'cundinamarca', 13013, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!, pero la matriz "c" no queda con el mismo orden de la matriz "b", el orden de los elementos cambia y toma el orden de la matriz "a" necesito que quede en el orden de la matriz "b", el orden de la matriz "a" no es el mismo de la "b"

Comment: Me puedes mostrar como seria con un ciclo for?

Comment: si claro, ahora lo agrego

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! muy buena explicacion.